# Does adding more applications to a Citrix session increase network usage?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, citrix

My understanding of the way Citrix works is that it basically sends screens from the server to the user at the other end.

If the server has more applications running can it increase the amount of network traffic used by Citrix or will it remain pretty much static?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking: No.

But if the Citrix server has to send *many* screen updates, than the network usage will go up. Especially if you watch videos.

Another thing that eats up bandwidth is device redirection, like USB sticks, and printing.

Daniel Feller is a lead software engineer at Citrix and has blogged about the basic ideas of bandwidth usage. This is from 2010 but it is general enough to still apply.

- Daniel Feller, 2010-05-20, [*How much bandwidth do I need for my virtual desktop?*](https://virtualfeller.com/2010/05/20/how-much-bandwidth-do-i-need-for-my-virtual-desktop/) <sub>(Archived [here](https://archive.is/SCoGG).)</sub>
- [Same post at Citrix Blogs](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2010/05/20/how-much-bandwidth-do-i-need-for-my-virtual-desktop/). More comments there.